# I need to insert the documents between the dates with help of past documents in mongodb collections

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have some documents from 13-july-2013 to 18-july-2013 in mongodb collections. but few days data was missed from collection. I need to insert that data with help of last five documents.

My data look like

```
{ 
  _id: 1,
  "timestamp": "2023-07-13T10:00:00Z"
  "code": "bc",
  "energy": 2333
},
{ 
  _id: 2,
  "timestamp": "2023-07-13T10:10:00Z"
  "code": "abc",
  "energy": 2340
},
{ 
  _id: 3,
  "timestamp": "2023-07-14T10:30:00Z"
  "code": "abc",
  "energy": 2349
},
{ 
  _id: 4,
  "timestamp": "2023-07-14T10:40:00Z"
  "code": "ah",
  "energy": 2355
},
{ 
  _id: 5,
  "timestamp": "2023-07-14T10:50:00Z"
  "code": "kk",
  "energy": 2360
},
{ 
  _id: 6,
  "timestamp": "2023-07-14T11:00:00Z"
  "code": "la",
  "energy": 2370
},
{ 
  _id: 7,
  "timestamp": "2023-07-14T10:00:00Z"
  "code": "as",
  "energy": 3455
},
{ 
  _id: 8,
  "timestamp": "2023-07-17T10:10:00Z"
  "code": "uj",
  "energy": 4567659
},
{ 
  _id: 9,
  "timestamp": "2023-07-17T10:30:00Z"
  "code": "la",
  "energy": 564546
},
{ 
  _id: 10,
  "timestamp": "2023-07-17T10:40:00Z"
  "code": "ws",
  "energy": 5654348
},
{ 
  _id: 11,
  "timestamp": "2023-07-18T10:50:00Z"
  "code": "lk",
  "energy": 6765436
},
{ 
  _id: 12,
  "timestamp": "2023-07-18T11:00:00Z"
  "code": "pl",
  "energy": 7654223
}
```

Here 15th and 16th data missed so I need insert these documents with update the energy field value, take the average of last 5 documents energy field value then mention that value in 15th date documents, like same as for next documents also, please help on this.

Output:

```
{ 
      _id: 1,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-13T10:00:00Z"
      "code": "bc",
      "energy": 2333
    },
    { 
      _id: 2,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-13T10:10:00Z"
      "code": "abc",
      "energy": 2340
    },
    { 
      _id: 3,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-14T10:30:00Z"
      "code": "abc",
      "energy": 2349
    },
    { 
      _id: 4,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-14T10:40:00Z"
      "code": "ah",
      "energy": 2355
    },
    { 
      _id: 5,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-14T10:50:00Z"
      "code": "kk",
      "energy": 2360
    },
    { 
      _id: 6,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-14T11:00:00Z"
      "code": "la",
      "energy": 2370
    },
    { 
      _id: 7,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-14T10:00:00Z"
      "code": "as",
      "energy": 2380
    },
     { 
      _id: 8,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-15T10:00:00Z"
      "code": "as",
      "energy": 9910
    },
     { 
      _id: 9,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-15T10:15:00Z"
      "code": "as",
      "energy": 11447
    },
     { 
      _id: 10,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-15T10:30:00Z"
      "code": "as",
      "energy": 19309.4
    },
     { 
      _id: 11,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-15T10:45:00Z"
      "code": "as",
      "energy": 29968
    },
     { 
      _id: 12,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-15T11:00:00Z"
      "code": "as",
      "energy": 49040
    },
     { 
      _id: 13,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-16T10:00:00Z"
      "code": "as",
      "energy": 80442
    },
     { 
      _id: 14,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-16T10:15:00Z"
      "code": "as",
      "energy": 1025852
    },
    { 
      _id: 16,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-17T10:10:00Z"
      "code": "uj",
      "energy": 4567659
    },
    { 
      _id: 17,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-17T10:30:00Z"
      "code": "la",
      "energy": 564546
    },
    { 
      _id: 18,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-17T10:40:00Z"
      "code": "ws",
      "energy": 5654348
    },
    { 
      _id: 19,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-18T10:50:00Z"
      "code": "lk",
      "energy": 6765436
    },
    { 
      _id: 20,
      "timestamp": "2023-07-18T11:00:00Z"
      "code": "pl",
      "energy": 7654223
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         day: {
            $dateTrunc: {
               date: "$timestamp",
               unit: "day",
               timezone: "Europe/Zurich"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         sortBy: { timestamp: 1 },
         output: {
            average: {
               $avg: "$energy",
               window: { documents: [-5, "current"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $densify: {
         field: "day",
         range: {
            step: 1,
            unit: "day",
            bounds: "full"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $fill: {
         sortBy: { day: 1, timestamp: 1 },
         output: {
            average: { method: "locf" }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         timestamp: { $ifNull: ["$timestamp", "$day"] },
         average: "$$REMOVE",
         energy: { $ifNull: ["$energy", "$average"] },
         day: "$$REMOVE",
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/elvUGO5O3Jf)

Note, `$fill` also provides a linear regression function which may fit even better.

**Update**

If you need data every 15 Minutes, then it is even simpler:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         sortBy: { timestamp: 1 },
         output: {
            average: {
               $avg: "$energy",
               window: { documents: [-5, "current"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $densify: {
         field: "timestamp",
         range: {
            step: 15,
            unit: "minute",
            bounds: "full"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $fill: {
         sortBy: { timestamp: 1 },
         output: {
            average: { method: "locf" }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         average: "$$REMOVE",
         energy: { $ifNull: ["$energy", "$average"] }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Thank you @Wernfried Domscheit, But here same energy value came for two days(15th, 16th) and I need to insert the records in every 15 min of time, not a day. Can you please help on this